# SwiftUI: Can someone help provide the code to include a navigation view, a search bar at the top, a list of items, and navigation links

Tags: swiftui

I am new to programming. I have been unable to find such code online where there is a search bar at the top of a navigation view, a scrollable list of items below with a navigation title, and navigation links to each item. Thank you in advance for your help.

**Countries.swift file**

```
import Foundation
 
struct Country: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let flag: String
    let name: String
    let capital: String
}

let countryList: [Country] = [
    Country(
        flag: "",
        name: "Philippines",
        capital: "Manila"),
    Country(
        flag: "",
        name: "France",
        capital: "Paris"),
    Country(
        flag: "",
        name: "Ireland",
        capital: "Dublin"),
    Country(
        flag: "",
        name: "Mexico",
        capital: "Mexico City"),
    Country(
        flag: "",
        name: "Canada",
        capital: "Ottawa"),
    Country(
        flag: "",
        name: "United States",
        capital: "Whashington D.C"),
    Country(
        flag: "",
        name: "Australia",
        capital: "Canberra"),
    Country(
        flag: "",
        name: "China",
        capital: "Beijing"),
    Country(
        flag: "",
        name: "United Kingdom",
        capital: "London")
]
```

**Details View file**

```
import SwiftUI
 
struct DetailsView: View {
    let countryItem: Country
     
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                ZStack {
                    Text(countryItem.flag)
                      .font(.largeTitle)
                      .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                      .padding(.trailing, 5)
                }
                Text(" \(countryItem.capital)")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(countryItem.name), displayMode: .automatic)
    }
}
```

**ContentView File**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State private var searchText = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        SearchBar(text: $searchText)
        NavigationView { List(countryList.filter({ searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.name.contains(searchText) })) { item in
            Text(item.name)
            List(countryList) { countryItem in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(countryItem: countryItem))
            .navigationBarTitle("Countries")
    }
}
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `NavigationView` should be at the top level -- right now, it's *within* your `List`

Comment: Please show your code in the question. Not an image of your code. Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started. The most important things are probably to have *one* `NavigationView` at the root of your view and *one* `List`:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var searchText = ""

    private var countryList = [Country(name:"Argentina"),Country(name:"Bolivia"),Country(name:"Brazil"),Country(name:"Columbia")]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                SearchBar(text: $searchText)
                List(countryList.filter({ searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.name.contains(searchText) })) { countryItem in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(countryItem: countryItem)) {
                        HStack {
                            ZStack {
                                Text(countryItem.flag)
                                    .font(.largeTitle)
                                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            }
                            Text(countryItem.name)
                                .font(.headline)
                        }.padding(7)
                    }
                    .navigationBarTitle("Countries")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have access to your `SearchBar` code, so I assume it's doing what you want already. If you're writing for iOS 15, I suggest you look into `searchable`: https://www.appcoda.com/swiftui-searchable/

Also, I didn't have your `countryList` code, so I replaced it with some of my own -- obviously, you could remove that.

Comment: This works! I just replaced your countrylist with my own file. Thank you so much for your help! Also, the searchBar file wouldn't upload onto here. I will get the hang of this site eventually hopefully